# Javascript Helper for Moving into sections of the screen

Tags: jquery, gridster

Can someone suggest a tool or library for my requirement?

I'd like to have some blocks on the screen with text in them that can be dragged into different sections of the screen where each section is a rectangle with a title. Ideally I'd like to call an api when I move a block into a rectangle to update the status.

I may need to build from scratch, but I was wondering if there was a tool a bit like gridster which would make it quicker to prototype.

Comment: Please re-evaluate your question - your requirements are vague, your question is difficult to answer and any answer is unlikely to apply well to other users of the site.

Comment: Not sure how to phrase the question. Would it help if I added a sketch?

Comment: If you can't describe your requirements in writing then you'll be unlikely to find a tool that can help. Clarity of intention is very important. Wireframes would help us to visualise the problem. Also, what is good / bad about Gridster in regards to your requirements? Good luck

Comment: It doesn't matter how clear the requirements are: Stack Overflow does not allow for software/library/tool recommendations. You can try over at [softwarerecs.se] but please be sure to check their posting rules before you ask. I believe they will require a clear list of objectives the tool should include

Comment: There's too many rules on this site. What's wrong with asking a question and getting some answers

Comment: This is a community resource. We answer these questions for free so that we build a useful, accurate and valuable source of information. You're not paying for help - if you won't take the time to think clearly about your problem so you can put together a coherent question, then please don't expect us to sacrifice our own time answering the question when we're doing it for free. I help on SO to add to the resource and and at a minimum that means decent answers to decent questions that can easily apply to many people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery draggable.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[Source](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Comment: Nice I will have a look